# Adjust div styled as pin location according to the div inside it using css

Tags: css

I have a question regarding showing a text inside a div styled as a pin location.

I am new to css and react (this is a css question) and I want to display a value in a div tag which has a pin location style, this value is a number and can be one digit or more.

To style the pin the used the following:

```
export const Mark = styled.div(props=>({
transform:"rotateX(20deg) rotateY(-45deg),
borderRadius: "50% 50% 50% 0",
padding:"50% 50% 50% 50%",
left:"50%",
top:"50%",
textAlign:"center",
position:"absolute",
width:"100%",
height:"100%")}
```

I am using other div for the value since I do not want the content (the number) to be rotated

```
<Mark><div style={{transform:"rotate(45deg)", left:"50%", top:"50%"}}100</div></Mark>
```

What I want is that: if the number has more digit the mark will be larger so all the digits will be inside it, and if one digit the Mark will be smaller. the numbers should be in the center(I believe this is already done by left 50% and top 50%")

Is that possible using certain styling?

Comment: I think that because the <Mark> element has a width property of 100% - there is no more space to grow... maybe cancel the width property and see what happened

Comment: @ ינון רחמים when I remove width 100% the shape of the pin changes and represents no pin (I believe this is because of the rotation I have made to the inner div)

Comment: this is weird.. in such cases i set a border to the elements to see where they are and understand what is going